# Difficult Eigenvalue Problem

Tags: differential-equations

I have an eigenvalue problem of the form:

f''(x)+V(x,lambda)f(x)=0

with Dirichlet boundary conditions:
f(a)=A
f(b)=B

The eigenvalues lambda are complex, so they have both a real and imaginary part.  How can I go about solving this eigenvalue problem?

Comment: What is `V`? This seems to be a nonlinear eigenvalue problem. I don't think that `NDEigensystem` can do that.

Comment: Why are your boundary conditions non-zero?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher: I agree with you, but I am not constrained to using NDEigensystem.  For example, I have tried some things with ParametricNDSolve.

Comment: @KraZug: Technically, they are not, but I thought I would pose a slightly more general problem in case I wanted to change them later.

Comment: @jenthsenth Well, what I tried to say: If there is an algorithm for it, you can certainly implement it in _Mathematica_ (it certainly will involve some fixed-point iterations scheme like Newton's method). But I do not know of any built-in method that does the job.

Comment: @jenthsenth, AFAIK BVP eigenvalue problems require zero boundary conditions.

Comment: I have a package (https://github.com/SPPearce/CompoundMatrixMethod) that is for solving these kind of linear differential equation BVP eigenvalue problems in 1D, which can cope with the nonlinear terms in $x$. If you post your actual equation then I can take a look at some point, or you can look at the other examples on this site where I have used my package (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=compoundmatrixmethod)